# Vega with SVI Gatheral bumps

Tags: volatility, equities, implied-volatility, modeling, greeks

How would one go about computing a vega profile of an exotic derivative where the volatility surface is modeled using Gatheral's SVI parameterization? In particular, I am thinking about bumping each of the params up by epsilon and computing a Jacobian for each time slice. So the vega explain would be computed like this:

Consider a time series of SVI parameterizations: $w_t(k;a,b,\rho, m, \sigma)$. Let $\mathscr{V}(t)$ be the vega explain along each slice. Then the vega explain would something like:

$$ \mathscr{V}(t) = \Delta a* \frac{\partial w_t}{\partial a} + \Delta b* \frac{\partial w_t}{\partial b} + \Delta \rho* \frac{\partial w_t}{\partial \rho}+ \Delta m* \frac{\partial w_t}{\partial m}+ \Delta \sigma* \frac{\partial w_t}{\partial \sigma} + \ldots$$

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How are you calculating the price of the derivative to begin with?

Comment: PDE pricing model which uses a local vol model. The implied vols use the SVI model. Dupire formula is used to move between implied and local vols

Comment: So why not try bumping the svi params and looking at the change in your price? Or applying a flat bump to your actual created vols and then repricing?

Comment: But how much to bump the params?

Comment: Why not try creating fitting many surfaces, and look at the range of values you get? Or why not try bumping the parameters by a range of values and seeing how (non)linear the price is as a function of the param?